# E-cart for e-commerce using django channels( without using ajax)

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, e-commerce, django-channels

I want to make E-cart for an e-commerce website using Django channels.. How can I do that? (I don't want to use ajax) is there anyway to get CRUD operation in real time without reloading the page from backend?

Comment: You have added the tag :django-channels. That's what you should go with.

Comment: But i don't know how to use channels.. Everywhere showing chat application using channels. But nowhere anyone making e-cart using django channels.

Answer (score 0):

you can acheive that using javascripts fetch api but its  the same as ajax

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I really want to build same thing with django channels